# VSCode `typeAcquisition` for browser imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, cdn, vscode-jsconfig

I want to have `.d.ts` typings for Lit which will be served from the `esm.sh` CDN. I want to use VSCode's built-in type acquisition system to get Intellisense for the Javascript files (which will be served directly to the user). I have tried to use a `jsconfig.json` file but have not figured out how to get it to work.

This is my configuration:

```json
{
    "typeAcquisition": {"include": ["lit", "lit-element", "lit-html"]}
}
```

I thought adding these would provide global type hints in all my Javascript files for these libraries. Is there any way to get the type hints without involving Node.js?